# Manage Dell workstations with OpenManage Essentials (OME)

Tags: dell, dell-openmanage, workstation-management

How can I manage Dell workstations with OpenManage Essentials ?

First, is it possible? Because iv read that only Dell servers can be managed with OME.

I would like to inventory each Dell workstations I have in my environment, and be able to see their service tag with warranty expiration, etc.

Or which product must I use to do this? There are so much Dell management products like OMCI, OMCC, ITA, etc!! I am so lost with all these products.

Comment: If you have enough Dell workstations to need to manage them, you should also have a vendor rep or support contract that you can ask these questions. Once you have technical questions, not product questions, come here and fire away!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OME is only for servers - it uses the BMC and DRAC which don't exist on workstations.

OMCI is what you want - you'll need DCM (Dell Client Manager) to gather data from all of the clients.

Comment: Also, whats about all the other Dell management products like ITA, OMSA, OMSM, etc. Also, it is very difficult to know if one of these product is still maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Keep an eye out for the next version of OME in Q4/2012 that will add a bit of client support.  www.delltechcenter.com/ome

Rob

ps. on your other question: OME pretty much replaces ITA.  OMSA is still up to date for your 1-to-1 management.  You can use OME + OMSA.

Comment: From where did you get this information please? Can you provide me with your source?